# Is there a actionscript3 lib to create *.ico file

Tags: actionscript, png, converters, ico

Now, i need to create a .ico file in my actionscript project. But I can not find a lib.

Here is [ICODecoder](http://www.libspark.org/svn/as3/ICODecoder/src/com/voidelement/images/ico/) (actionscript lib) for reading ico file and get the bitmap data.

But what i really need is conver jpg/png to .ico file.

Comment: After some googling it seems to me, that no open source solution exists..but heres a Flex app http://converticon.com/ , that does what you need, perhaps if you write him, he'll give you his encoder

Answer (score 0):

There is no library that I have ever seen to create an ico file; however, nothing is stopping you from creating a back-end service that when contacted by an ActionScript call, it creates the .ico file for you, stores it on the server, and your ActionScript fetches it when it's ready.